# Django preferences/Boolean fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that requires quite a few BooleanFields, they could be considered preferences in some way. What I'm currently doing is adding all the fields to the model itself and hardcoding the labels to the HTML.  So my model looks somewhat like this:

```
 class Project(models.Model):
  ...some fields...
  Check1=models.BooleanField()
  ....many of these...
  Check19=models.BooleanField()
```

I feel this is a very dumb way of doing it and am looking for a more Pythonic solution. Maybe ManyToMany fields? Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you're not *really* calling them "Check<n>"...

Comment: Not quite. But using simple notation allows for simple (and error-prone, I know) iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather give the boolean fields some meaningful names and would put verbose_name to the field description, e.g.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # ...
    featured = models.BooleanField(_("Featured"))
    published = models.BooleanField(_("Published"))
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are all of the same type, it would probably make sense to make it a M2M, e.g. `phone1`, `phone2`, `phone3`, etc. would be more appropriate as `phones` pointing to a `Phone` model.

However, since these are booleans, I doubt that's the case. Having a lot of fields on a model is not a problem, if they all make sense there. It would be *wrong*, in fact, to abstract them away, when they have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

Especially:

- Simple is better than complex.
- Complex is better than complicated.
- Flat is better than nested.